# adjust position of labels for Shiny controls

Tags: r, shiny, data-visualization

I'm surprised that this hasn't come up on StackOverflow before, but anyway here's the question:

Currently, the label text, "Age Range", is specified here

`sliderInput(inputId="age", "Age Range", min=32, max=99, value=c(32, 99), step=1)`

...and shows up on the top, by default.

[image]

How can I control the position of the labels, specifically, how can I place the label to the left of the actual slider?

Do I need to remove the "Age Range" argument from the function and then use HTML? Is there some way to dig into the bootstrap behind it all?

Comment: Hey Matt, did you find an answer to this? I am having the same problem and say I want the sliderInput to be shown in front of Age Range not under it. If you can share the solution with me, that would be great.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't found a solution at this time.

Answer (score 1):

Note that I am not an export for CSS, so most likely there are better solutions. The input functions in shiny (v0.11.1) *simply* return HTML; in your example the return value is:

```
sliderInput(inputId="age", "Age Range", min=32, max=99, value=c(32, 99), step=1)
<div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
<label class="control-label" for="age">Age Range</label>
<input class="js-range-slider" id="age" data-type="double" data-min="32" data-max="99" data-from="32" data-to="99" data-step="1" data-grid="true" data-grid-num="9.57142857142857" data-grid-snap="false" data-prettify-separator="," data-keyboard="true" data-keyboard-step="1.49253731343284"/>
</div>
```

So you have to adjust the `label` element relative to the `input` element. To do this I wrap these elements in a new `div` to be able to assign an `id`. Then you can modify the layout for `label` and `input` inside that id:

```
div(id = "myDiv", sliderInput(inputId="age", "Age Range", min=32, max=99, value=c(32, 99), step=1))
<div id="myDiv">
...
</div>
```

And for modification I add the following to the *page-function* (e.g. `fluidPage`) as argument:

```
tags$head(tags$style(HTML("div#myDiv label { width: 20%; }
                           div#myDiv input { display: inline-block; width: 80%;}")))
```

In this setting the label gets 20% of the row width and the input element 80. `display: inline-block;` is needed so the label and input will be on the same line. I think this is one solution to adjust the position of the label relative to its input element.